# Jquery ondrop event is not equal with inline ondrop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my working code:

```js
function dodrop(event)  {
  var dt = event.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;
  var count = files.length;
  output("File Count: " + count + "\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   output(" File " + i + ":\n(" + (typeof files[i]) + ") : <" + files[i] + " > " + files[i].name + " " + files[i].size + "\n");
  }
}

function output(text) {
  $('.drag-and-drop').text($('.drag-and-drop').text() + text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="output" class="drag-and-drop" style="min-height: 200px; white-space: pre; border: 1px solid black;"
   ondragenter="document.getElementById('output').textContent = ''; event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();"
   ondragover="event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();"
   ondrop="event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault(); dodrop(event);">
      DROP FILES HERE FROM FINDER OR EXPLORER
  </div>
```

This code shows information about the dropped file and  it's working fine.

But, if I remove the inline events from div tag and use Jquery it doesn't work the same. I tried to convert the inline events to jQuery events like this:

```js
    $('.drag-and-drop').on('dragenter', function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
     event.preventDefault();
    });
    
    $('.drag-and-drop').on('dragover', function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
     event.preventDefault();
    });
    
    $('.drag-and-drop').on('drop', function(event){
     event.stopPropagation(); 
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log(event);
     dodrop(event);
    });

function dodrop(event)  {
      var dt = event.dataTransfer;
      var files = dt.files;
      var count = files.length;
      output("File Count: " + count + "\n");
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       output(" File " + i + ":\n(" + (typeof files[i]) + ") : <" + files[i] + " > " + files[i].name + " " + files[i].size + "\n");
     }
    }

    function output(text) {
      $('.drag-and-drop').text($('.drag-and-drop').text() + text);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output" class="drag-and-drop" style="min-height: 200px; white-space: pre; border: 1px solid black;">
  DROP FILES HERE FROM FINDER OR EXPLORER
</div>
```

But in the jQuery drop event, the returned event is not equal with the returned event from inline ondrop. I think I need to edit my jQuery code but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to put the events in a `(document).ready()` function or a 'live' version of the `on()` function? If your javascript is executed before the html elements where parsed then you wont have added the events because the elements where not there yet on script execution.

Comment: Yes. actually, the problem is that in jquery it can not find the "files" item in the event. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined"

Comment: Yes the jquery event object is a bit different to the html event object. Try `dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer` in your jQuery functions.

Comment: Ah! thanks. It works fine..

Comment: Glad I could help. Posted it as an answer for other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery event object is a bit different to the DOM event object. You can access the original event object by calling the `originalEvent` attribute.

```
dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer
```